# Pie Display cutout window attribute change is not reflecting in making the videoview fullscreen

Tags: android

I am changing the window attribute with user gesture like swipe.

```
getWindow().getAttributes().layoutInDisplayCutoutMode = LAYOUT_IN_DISPLAY_CUTOUT_MODE_SHORT_EDGES;
```

My activity is not extending to full screen. Where as if the same line is used in onCreate method, view is rendering in full screen underneath the cutout. But if I try to do the same action with some user touch event/gesture, it doesn't work.

My question is: with the new cutout mode set to window, how can we apply those window attributes to our view to make our view appear in full screen?

Thanks in advance.